# GOM player not running video

Tags: mediaplayer, video

I am trying to run movie on GOM player for Mac, when I open the movie, GOM player name appears on top of menu bar, but no player appears.

The same .avi file opened well in VLC player. I found out that if there is any other file of same name as .avi but of different extension exist in the folder, GOM player won't run that .avi file. As I have XVZ.avi and XYZ.srt, player didn't opened the file, then I changed the file name to XYZ2.avi. It opened.

What could be the issue?

Comment: GOM Player is Windows-only, so why ask here?

Comment: I guess you are a bit outdated, gom player has Mac port also

Comment: Sorry, my search at the time didn't yield any good result. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's an issue with GOM Player subtitle renderer.

It's probably trying to open/read the subtitles but fails and this failure makes it impossible to play the video (it's probably a bug in GOM Player, since most player would just skip the subtitle and play the movie anyway).

I'd suggest you try another player, [**VLC**](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is fine, [**Perian**](http://perian.org) works great with QuickTime or [**MPlayerX**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mplayerx/id421131143?mt=12) which is free on the Mac App Store. And they all play subtitles, also.

Comment: Thanks, I love GOM player as its controls are more friendly as can fast forward using arrow keys....

Comment: I think MPlayerX does that also

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your GOM Player SKIN to "BASIC", if it is not.